# Android - ANR Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF }

Tags: android, bitmap, broadcast, android-anr-dialog, screen-off

I'm getting ANR on this method

```
    private byte[] getByteArrayFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

I don't know how can I improve it. this is the stack trace also I can't reproduce it. getting this stack from the google play console.

```
    main (native):tid=1 systid=24352 
#00 pc 0x4b38c libc.so (syscall + 28)
#01 pc 0x1af92c libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 148)
#02 pc 0x3f077c libart.so (art::JNI<false>::SetByteArrayRegion(_JNIEnv, _jbyteArray, int, int, signed char const*) + 504)
#03 pc 0x1ba3bc libhwui.so (SkJavaOutputStream::write(void const*, unsigned long) + 92)
#04 pc 0x3ca55c libhwui.so (sk_write_fn(png_struct_def, unsigned char, unsigned long) + 48)
#05 pc 0x2d990 libpng.so (png_compress_IDAT + 560)
#06 pc 0x31834 libpng.so (png_write_find_filter + 3180)
#07 pc 0x2aae0 libpng.so (png_write_row + 796)
#08 pc 0x2a7a8 libpng.so (png_write_rows + 44)
#09 pc 0x3cb264 libhwui.so (SkPngEncoder::onEncodeRows(int) + 172)
#10 pc 0x3cb350 libhwui.so (SkPngEncoder::Encode(SkWStream*, SkPixmap const&, SkPngEncoder::Options const&) + 112)
#11 pc 0x3c931c libhwui.so (SkEncodeImage(SkWStream*, SkPixmap const&, SkEncodedImageFormat, int) + 92)
#12 pc 0x1da614 libhwui.so (android::Bitmap::compress(SkBitmap const&, android::Bitmap::JavaCompressFormat, int, SkWStream*) + 292)
#13 pc 0x1da460 libhwui.so (android::Bitmap::compress(android::Bitmap::JavaCompressFormat, int, SkWStream*) + 84)
#14 pc 0x1b2d3c libhwui.so (Bitmap_compress(_JNIEnv, _jobject, long, int, int, jobject, jbyteArray) + 136)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Bitmap.java)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1467)
       at com.lock.services.NotificationService.getByteArrayFromBitmap(NotificationService.java)
       at com.lock.services.NotificationService.sendNotification(NotificationService.java:2)
       at com.lock.services.NotificationService.m113x428d563f(NotificationService.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7766)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to make `getByteArrayFromBitmap()` runing on background threads.